# how to check session flashdata in helper in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

To check and display a session, I usually do this:

```
        $alert = $this->session->flashdata('alert');

        if($alert)
        {
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <?php echo $var; ?>
            </div> <?php
        }
```

But the result is sloppy. I want to make a "ECHO" of a function and that function contains everything you need to check and display the session. So I try to do this in form helper:

```
function errors_session()
{
   $ci =& get_instance();

   if( $this->ci->session->flashdata() == TRUE )
   {
      return '<div class="error">'. $this->ci->session->flashdata() .'</div>';
   }

   return '';
}
```

but this not work

Comment: And what is the problem with your code? Where is your function defined? What does your function call look like?

Comment: Hi,
I try to do is print the function "errors_session()" in a view to display messages with Flashdata session. The problem is that in the view I get the following error
"Fatal error: Using $ this When not in object context"

Comment: Answer below. Its a good question you should edit to add the error you were getting as I think its a common problem

Answer (score 1):

in Controller file:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('Success', 'You are Successfully Logged.');
```

in View file:

```
 if($this->session->flashdata('Success')){
  //your content
}
```

or

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('Success');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah should have spotted that. Its as the error says- you can't use $this you need to change to use the $ci object you have created like this

```
$ci->session->flashdata()
```